# Javascript delay after click, set timeout not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Thanks in advance for helping. I am new to JavaScript so i think i'm doing something basic incorrectly. I would like `'toggleclass'` between class `'.fa'` and class `'.fa-bars fa-times'` to take 1 second after i click on class `'.ubermenu-responsive-toggle'`

The toggle between `'.fa'` and `'.fa-bar fa times'` after clicking on `'.ubermenu-responsive-toggle'` works. I just can't get the timeset delay down. I keep getting JavaScript errors in Chrome's inspector. I will put my best guess below. I'm sure this is something simple but, like I said, JavaScript is new territory for me. 
Thanks again for your help.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $( '.ubermenu-responsive-toggle' ).on( 'click touchend' , setTimeout(function(){
      jQuery( this ).find( '.fa' ).toggleClass( 'fa-bars fa-times' );
   }, 1000));
});
```

Comment: What console error is it giving ? `setTimeout` is working properly. See [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ht70kc4z/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be carefull with object "this" inside a setTimeout or setInterval function, because maybe could not be the object that you expect, try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
    $( '.ubermenu-responsive-toggle' ).on( 'click touchend' , function() {
        var $myToggles = $(this).find( '.fa' );

        setTimeout(function() {
             $myToggles.toggleClass('fa-bars fa-times');
        }, 1000);
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jose. This got the job done. I hope that there comes a day when I can contribute to the forum in a meaningful way. Stackoverflow is a great site. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Try utilizing [.delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay) , [.queue()](http://api.jquery.com/queue)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".ubermenu-responsive-toggle").on("click touchend", function(e) {
    jQuery(this).delay(1000, "toggle").queue("toggle", function() {
      jQuery(this).find(".fa").toggleClass("fa-bars fa-times");
    }).dequeue("toggle");
  });
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pLv0n1w4/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.ubermenu-responsive-toggle').on('click touchend', function () {
        var that=jQuery(this);
        setTimeout(function () {
            that.find('.fa').toggleClass('fa-bars fa-times');
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```