# How to toggle classes in sequence

Tags: jquery

How can I add a class to a div, wait a second, remove the class, then add another?

```
$(".bauble_01").toggleClass("sway-left").delay(1000).toggleClass("sway-right");
```

I was hoping the above would add "sway-left", wait a second, then remove "sway-left" and add "sway-right" but it does it at the same time... the delay doesn't seem to work?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The duplicate will help you understand why `delay()` does not behave as you expect, but note your current code does not remove the `sway-left` class either.

Comment: `toggleClass` isnt queued, use [`queue`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.queue/)

Comment: You can also utilize `.promise()`, `.then()`, `setTimeout()` or `.animate()` to achieve expected result.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Note, linked Question and Answer does not actually describe how to solve current Question using `.queue()` and `.delay()` without an animation queue.

Comment: @guest, it does explain how to use delay() to introduce an actual delay between two synchronous operations, though. Of course, if you find a more appropriate duplicate, feel free to suggest it.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Providing a name for the queue at `.delay()`, `.queue()` allows functions to be queued without using default `"fx"` animation queue http://stackoverflow.com/a/30001155/

Comment: Ok thanks - all - I didnt really understand these comments - but got it working with a setTimeout to call the 2nd toggle function after the first. Works well: